# How to open only one file out of multiple selected files without losing the selection?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

I'm trying to delete multiple files from a folder, but there are times where I want to open one file to check it's content. When I select multiple files, if I just right click and open, Windows will either open all the files I have selected or open the last selected file. If I left click on the specific file I want to open, I lose my selection. How can I open only the file I'm right clicking on without losing my selection and having to select everything again?

Comment: This is the COM object a third party program would use - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nf-shldisp-ishellfolderviewdual-get_focuseditem. I'm not aware of any such program.